# `python --version` not returning any result

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

So I was using `pythonV3` for the past few months. But then I somehow messed up my Python installation.

So I decided to start from scratch: I uninstalled all Python from my computer and reinstalled `Python3.8.1`. Or at least I thought I did.

When I try to check which version of Python I have by using the `python --version` or `python3 --version` commands, I get no message at all. No error message and no confirmation message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uninstalled Python one more time and then re-installed. But this time, I **checked** the box that "Added Python to PATH".

Now, the command "python --version" returns the expected Python 3.8.1.

The only reason I did not check the box the first time around was because I thought it was better/best practice to stick with whatever defaults the installation dialog box came with.

Comment: This helped me. I did the same thing thinking that the default was the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the environment variables is the Python3.8.1 path added in system variable path?
   Are you able run python to enter into python interpreter?

```
C:\Users\itachi>python --version
Python 3.8.1

C:\Users\itachi>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my pc to Windows 11 and encountered the same situation.

I looked for Python and installed it from Microsoft Store, which helps fix the problem.

So, try installing Python from **Microsoft Store** instead of the Python site

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).